# SQL query giving strange results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a SQL query which gives me strange results. Here are the tables:

`U1Base` has information about `movie ratings` given by users - it includes the `user ID, movie ID and Rating` given by the user to the movie (also additional information not relevant to the question)

`U1Test` has the same columns as U1Base and is used for testing the results of the calculations on U1Base

these two tables are imported from MovieLens so they are beyond reproach (I did need to clean some of the data but it was only one row out of 80000)

`S1_Similarity` includes the similarity measure between every two users in the database

I want to calculate a prediction for the rating a user would give a movie he/she have not watched. For this I want to extrapolate from u1base and compare the results to u1test.

u1test has 20000 rows.

Here is the query I use for selecting:

```
SELECT test.user_id, 
       test.movie_id,
       sum(cast(base.rating as float))/5 
  FROM u1test AS test, 
       u1base AS base
 WHERE     base.user_id<>test.user_id
       AND base.movie_id=test.movie_id
       AND base.user_id IN (
                       SELECT TOP 5 user_id2 
                         FROM s1_similarity 
                        WHERE user_id1=test.user_id 
                     ORDER BY similarity desc
            )
GROUP BY 
       test.user_id,test.movie_id
```

For some reason this query does not return 20,000 rows as I expected. If I increase the parameter for top it includes more rows. I thought that each row in u1test will be given a calculated average.

What am I doing wrong?

Dotan

Comment: How many results do you get back?
My initial thinking is that you need a left outer join on u1base but I'm still trying to follow it through

Comment: Does every record in s1_similarity has a record in the table where the users are interchanged? I.e. if user u1 and user u2 have a similarity score of 5, will there be both a record (u1, u2, 5) and a record (u2, u1, 5) in the similarity table? Because otherwise, you might be missing data...

Comment: You ill got only the rows match the join and filter (btw, implicit joins are ugly and mess up declaring both in the where clause, try to use explicit joins) it means not all test.users had evaluated all movies the base.users has evaluated.